# How do I populate an HTML text box by counting the number of checked checkboxes in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a simple `HTML` `form` with about 10 `checkboxes` and a text field to the right of them. What I want to do is count the number of `checkboxe`s that are `checked` and display this number in the text field to the right as soon as they are checked. My `form` is looking like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox"/>
  <input id="totalbox" type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

I've looked around on Stack but haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the count in jQuery:

```
$('#totalbox').val($('#myForm input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
```

To get the count in pure JavaScript:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
var inputs = myForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
var count = 0;
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type')=='checkbox' && inputs[i].checked) count++;    
}
document.getElementById('totalbox').value = count;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
 $(":checkbox").change(function(){
  /* $(":checkbox:checked") will select all checkboxes in entire document, if you want for your form only then you can use my $("#myForm:checkbox:checked")  */
  $('#totalbox').val($(":checkbox:checked").length);

 });
```

Comment: A comment indicating that this will select *all* checkboxes in the entire document would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some non-jQuery logic:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="box" name="checkbox" onchange="countChecks();"/>
    <input id="totalbox" type="text" value="" />
</form>

<script>
function countChecks() {
    var chks = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0, l = chks.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (chks[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (chks[i].checked) {
                total++;
            };
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("totalbox").value = total;
}
</script>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Well since most of the responses are `jquery` even though there's no `jquery` tag and rest are long ones, here's a small js version:

```
var checkboxes= document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', checked)
}
function checked(){
   var checkboxes= document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
   document.getElementById('totalbox').value= checkboxes.length;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7GZMw/)

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery to achieve something like this.

```
$(function($){
    $('#myForm input:checkbox').click( function(){
       $('#totalbox').val( $('#myForm :checkbox:checked').length );
    });
});
```